# Opamp resistor arrangement to get out of its noise

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, bootstrap

In the [balanced line technoloy](http://www.douglas-self.com/ampins/balanced/balanced.htm) text, the author mentioned that we can't have a large resistor for R1 in this circuit:

[image: variabe gain amplifer with resitor value constraint]

The author said:

> For a series-feedback stage, the input impedance can be made as high as desired by bootstrapping.

How I can change the circuit to be able to use a high resistance value?

Comment: "How I can change the circuit to be able to use a high resistance value?" You have already accepted an answer. Does the answer you accepted answer your question?  Would you like more answers?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I've satisfied, but more explanation exists, I really can't wait to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the figure you show is his Figure 8, from the table earlier on that website page. That table says that figure 7 is a series-feedback stage. He seems to mean a conventional noninverting opamp circuit as shown in figure 7.
[image: Self figure 7]
I've not heard this described as a bootstrapping circuit before, but that may refer to the fact that the feedback acts to keep the - input at the same instantaneous voltage as the + input. If the opamp input is a bipolar long tailed pair, then the current into the + input will barely change as the + input voltage increases, because of this feedback.

Comment: Oh I think you are right (Upvote), thanks, but what is the bootstrap technique used in this picture?

Comment: Answer edited. Hope it's right!

Comment: You mean the feedback is cancelling the noise? Or maybe Doglus has written incorrectly? And maybe opamps have internal bootstraping?

Comment: The noise Self is worried about is generated in the source resistance, johnson noise. In the first figure, R1 is in series with the source resistance and its noise adds to the source resistance noise, so R1 must not be too big. In the second figure, there is nothing in series with the source resistance, the source resistance is the only noise generator, and you can get the best noise possible with whatever source you have. BTW Self's books on audio power amp design are very good, well worth reading.

Comment: Why high opamp impedance does not generate noise?

Comment: No. If I imagine a 1 MΩ resistor from the + input to ground, any noise current from that would be shorted out by the resistance of the signal source to ground. Having a low source impedance helps reduce amplifier noise.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, it means shunt resistors are not contributing at least in low resistance sorce case.